# How do I handle claim check with cqrs

Tags: c#, cqrs, rebus

TL;DR:
 1. Am I creating an anti-pattern?
 2. What is the best way to handle a claim check with CQRS?

I have several entry points in my system (webapi passing in json and xml), as well as through the file system with fixed-length files.

I am using Rebus with MSMQ and Sql server to manage my messaging.  The data can be larger than 4mb (MSMQ's max message size if I believe).  When the system receives a file I convert it into a stream and create a command that implements IAttachmentCommand as below:

```
public interface IAttachmentCommand : ICommand
{
    Stream Attachment { get; }

    IClaimCheckCommand ToClaimCheck(string attachmentId);
}

public interface IClaimCheckCommand : ICommand
{
    string AttachmentId { get; }
}
```

I then send it using a command bus (using Rebus).  If the command is of type IAttachmentCommand I create an attachment in the rebus databus table and return a new IAttachmentCommand using ToClaimCheck on the original command.  The AttachmentCommand is effectively a carbon copy of the original command, except it now has the attachmentId instead of the data.

I will then call send in my Rebus bus with my new AttachmentId as below:

```
public void Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
{
  if (command is IAttachmentCommand)
  {
    var cmd = command as IAttachmentCommand;
    var task = CreateAttachment(cmd);  // method excluded, but persists to Rebus DataBus and returns AttachmentId
    var claimCheck = task.Result;
    _activator.Bus.Send(claimCheck);
  }
  else
  {
    _activator.Bus.Send(command);
  }
}
```

This seems to be working, although I am happy to have my code pulled to shreds.  I can send commands, apply the events that are generated by my aggregate roots, persist to the event store etc etc.

I simply pick up a file from a webapi call or the file system, create a command and send it off with my command bus.

In a separate windows service I have a command dispatcher monitoring MSMQ for these messages.  When a message comes in it will then iterate through however many CommandValidationHandlers there are to validate the command.  CommandValidationHandlers implement the following:

```
public interface ICommandValidationHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
   ValidationResult Validate(TCommand command);
}
```

ValidationResult effectively returns a collection of errors.  These errors are logged, published as an InvalidCommand event that contains the Command info and the errors - this then allows me to have any subscribers that are listening pick up the event - send a mail or call a web service etc to say that the message failed, with the reasons.  If the command is invalid an exception is then thrown and the process stops.

My concern is that on validation I have the attachmentId, and have to retrieve the file, which is then validated, for example against an xsd.

From there I need to deserialize it to an object (generally a collection of financial transactions with a header which contains meta data such as no of transactions etc) and perform extra validation on data in the object.

Once this validation is complete I need to iterate through the collection of transactions in the object and send these to their relevant bounded contexts using the command bus, and further processing takes place.

It seems in this instance that I will be hitting the claim store a number of times - once for each validation handler (although I guess this could be resolved with a composite collection of validators), but then again in the Command Handler once validation has taken place.

In the various Event Handlers I have that need access to all the data I need to retrieve the data from the claim store each time and deserialize a number of times.

This seems like code-smell to me.  Should I consider caching the file the first time I retrieve it and clear it from cache once all event handlers have finished their work?

Does anybody have better suggestions?

Comment: If using caching, are there any cases that the cache must be invalidated?

Comment: The data is immutable, but can be removed from cache - for example if cpu starts getting hit too much with 1000s of records, if I decided to place an expiry on cache or once all event handlers subscribing to the message have received it.  I guess it would then be wise to keep a reference to the AttachmentId even when I have the attachment - that way I could lazy load it if it has been removed from cache.

Comment: The cache pattern is good but caching has the disavantage of being **hard** to invalidate when source of truth canges. If this is not your case then use it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about your problem the question is really: "should I use a caching mechanism for reading the `claim store` on the validation handlers?"

In your case, because the data in the `claim store` is immutable, you could cache it as long as you need it. That is the beauty of the immutable data: is *forever* cacheable.

To implement the caching mechanism you could use the decorator pattern over the `claim store` and switch to the cached version in your `composition root` in the `dependency container`. In this way you can anytime switch back to the uncached one.

You could cache it even more, you could cache even the result of the validation if the validated data does not ever change and it is repeated over time.